# How do you know a soap client is using https/ssl? Using php nusoap library

Tags: php, security

I'm using a PHP soap toolkit called nusoap (http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap), and I have a newbie question.

I am calling a WSDL service, which is running over ssl (e.g. https://server.com/service/method.asmx?WSDL).

Using nusoap, I traced out the request.  It looks like this:

```
POST /service/method.asmx HTTP/1.0
Host: server.com
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
SOAPAction: "http://software.com/service/Method"
Content-Length: 713
```

I'm wondering, though, is this being done over SSL, or no?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see the actual traffic. Then it'll be fairly obvious if its encrypted or not.

Answer (score 1):

`SOAPAction: "http://software.com/service/Method"` indicates it's probably not using SSL. You'd expect it to have `https` in that URI.  I certainly wouldn't trust it.